# Check if the gateway is accessible before starting VPN connection

Tags: powershell, vpn, gateway

I'm working on powershell dialer for calling after some steps a VPN tool.

One step is for the user, the selection of the device which is used for establish the connection. During this step I'm searching how I could test the VPN gateway, because if this test doesn't work, this mean that user could have a connection problem, like captive portal (if he try to connect from a hotel). So if this test failed, it's not neccessary to go further.

I have try with this :

```
$ip ="x.x.x.x"
if(Test-Connection -computername $ip -count 1 -quiet){
write-host "gateway is accessible"
}
```

The problem is : connection is OK and the VPN also (if I try connect), but I get no response from this script. Maybe It's not the correct way to test it.

Config : Win 7 / Powershell 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my solution with [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7a3304c7-b564-4acc-ab28-2648a20f4bce/telnet-using-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell)

By using this :

```
if(New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient -ArgumentList '$iSERVER','$PORT') {...}
```

It's working well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have some sort of captive portal testing web service. As you said, Test-Connection cannot deal with things like captive portals, it just look at the network interface state.

Typically, you have a fixed URL with expected output. For instance, you set up a web server with URL mytestconnection/test and it outputs OK

Then you do Invoke-WebRequest on that URL and if it doesn't say OK it means there is a problem.

Comment: Is there possible to take another way and send something with udp to the vpn server and wait the response ?

Comment: I guess that is possible too. Either way reduce the timeout limit for better experience.

Comment: I guess that is possible too. Either way reduce the timeout limit for better experience.